# How do I randomly spawn enemies(Kinematicbod) in Vector3

Tags: gdscript

I am making my first 3d fps in Godot and I don't understand how to spawn enemies in a general area. If someone could show me a tutorial or something that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Make a scene with only your enemy character, Give it control scripts as needed (movement, etc), and save it as a scene (Ex: myEnemy.tscn).

In your main script (or wherever you're calling it from), load the enemy scene and store it as a variable by writing:

`onready var loadedEnemy = preload("res://myEnemy.tscn")`

Then in your `_process()` or `_ready()` function (depending on what you need it for):

1. Instance the enemy by writing

`var enemy = loadedEnemy.instance()`

2. Add the instance to the scene with

`add_child(enemy)`

3.Specify the location of the enemy placement. For a random placement somewhere in a 10 x 10  area on the ground level (Y=0) by writing

`enemy.transform.origin = Vector3( rand_range(0,10), 0,  rand_range(0,10) )`

You can also specify rotation with

`enemy.transform.basis = Vector3(90deg, 0, 0)` (example)

You can add more enemies by repeating these steps beginning from `var enemy = loadedEnemy.instance()` (Ex: The next enemy would be `var enemy2 = loadedEnemy.instance()`)

If you need them to appear at different times, add them in the `on_timer_timeout()` function of a different `Timer` nodes.

Good Luck